# Getting jQuery drag-drop to working on iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, drag-and-drop

I have some custom drag-drop written in jQuery and want to be able to do the same on a iPad.

Here is the my code

```
    $('.item').draggable({
        opacity:0.7,
        helper:'clone',
        cursorAt:{
            top:0,
            left:0
        }
    });

$('.selected-plan').droppable({
        drop:queryBuilder.drop,
        opacity:0.1,
        hoverClass:'item-arrived'
    });
```

Now I did some research and looked up @ http://popdevelop.com/2010/08/touching-the-web/ and made some changes, like only for the drag, to test it, but it didn't seem to work

```
$.('.item').draggable = function() {
  var offset = null;
  var start = function(e) {
    var orig = e.originalEvent;
    var pos = $(this).position();
    offset = {
      x: orig.changedTouches[0].pageX - pos.left,
      y: orig.changedTouches[0].pageY - pos.top
    };
  };
  var moveMe = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var orig = e.originalEvent;
    $(this).css({
      top: orig.changedTouches[0].pageY - offset.y,
      left: orig.changedTouches[0].pageX - offset.x
    });
  };
  this.bind("touchstart", start);
  this.bind("touchmove", moveMe);
};
```

I have also looked at http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/, but couldn't find a way to change my code to fit it and get it working.

Any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once used mapping touchevents to mouseevents to enable drag and drop (jQuery UI's `draggable`) on touch devices. Worked like this:

```
function touchHandler(event) {
    var touches = event.changedTouches;
    var first = touches[0];
    var type = "";

    switch (event.type) {
    case "touchstart":
        type = "mousedown";
        break;
    case "touchmove":
        type = "mousemove";
        break;
    case "touchend":
        type = "mouseup";
        break;
    default:
        return;
    }

    //initMouseEvent(type, canBubble, cancelable, view, clickCount, 
    //           screenX, screenY, clientX, clientY, ctrlKey, 
    //           altKey, shiftKey, metaKey, button, relatedTarget);
    var simulatedEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent(type, true, true, window, 1, first.screenX, first.screenY, first.clientX, first.clientY, false, false, false, false, 0 /*left*/ , null);

    first.target.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);
    event.preventDefault();
}​
```

as a handler and then you'd map the events like:

```
document.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, true);
document.addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, true);
document.addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, true);
document.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchHandler, true);
```

With this event mapping done you could just use it like in a "mouse-driven" environment.

Worked fine, although it of course is a little limited as you lose things like multiple touches.

Comment: This is awesome, work well, but now the clicking on buttons / datepicker is not working, any solution for that?

Comment: @livingtolearn it shouldn't mess with clicks, at least it didn't when I used it. Are you binding touch events to the elements in question?

Comment: kind of, because once the element is dragged and dropped, I am append the element with a textbox or a datepicker, now I tried to comment out the preventDefault(), and the click work, but on the iPad the entire screen also moves :(

Comment: @livingtolearn I have to admit that your comment is a little hard to decypher but are you looking for sth like this: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494815/Preventing-Scrolling-on-iPhone-Phonegap-Applications

Comment: I kind of got the calendar also to work, but unable to select a date, but i can type the date :). Also I will have to really customize the JS. Ofcouse I need a css for the iPhone and 1 for the desktops.

Answer (score 0):

We used the javascript function elementFromPoint to replace the mouseOver once, when the elements match you can do a call.